# How to test machine learning model with real data in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning thing and python. I have created a simple linear regression model in python . I can test the accuracy of my model but only for the data in my data set , my data set is a csv file which contains a relation between salary and years of experience . But I want to use it in practical life . Like  I will input the years of experience and the output will be predicted salary .  Here is what I have done so far

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
"""from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)
sc_y = StandardScaler()
y_train = sc_y.fit_transform(y_train)"""

# Fitting Simple Linear Regression to the Training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

I want to modify the above code in such way, that I can give input years of experience and the output will expected salary .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: `regressor.predict([years_of_experience])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your trained model to make a prediction. 
  As a previous answer mentioned, you would want to use

```
regressor.predict([years_of_xp])
```

This will ask your model to make a prediction of the salary someone will recieve, given years_of_xp years of experience.

Answer (score 2):

After training the model, save your model to file and load it later in order to make predictions. In Python, you can use 'pickle' to achieve this.

References:

[scikit-learn Model Persistence](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)

[save and load machine learning models, an example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/)